# Permission denied for COPY file on valid directory

Tags: postgresql, file-permissions

My PostgreSQL v10 is running on a UBUNTU server. The user group `www-data` contains the user `postgres`, as checked by  `grep ^www-data /etc/group`. When I do `sudo chown -R :postgres MyPath`  it works fine, but when I change to `sudo chown -R :www-data MyPath` it not works.

How to set permissions for *postgres* user access other user group?

---

NOTES

- As @LaurenzAlbe suggested on comment, the `ls -ld myPath` is `drwxrwxr-x 29 root postgres 4096 Feb 27 15:54 myPath`
- and `id postgres` is `uid=112(postgres) gid=117(postgres) groups=117(postgres),33(www-data),116(ssl-cert)`

Comment: Please show `ls -ld MyPath` and `id postgres`.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe, I edited with the results.